How to clear persistent "Normal" style, after exporting from Google Docs
All right, this is really bugging me. I started a document in Google Docs and worked on it for several weeks. Finally needing some more advanced formatting options, I exported it to a Microsoft Word .docx file and opened it in the desktop app Microsoft Word 365 for Enterprise (Version 2403, Build 17425.20176 Click-to-Run).
From the moment I first did the import, I noticed there was something "off". The text had a background color:

It's barely noticeable, but it's enough to really niggle my OCD.
Especially when I discovered I couldn't remove it. It seems to be "burned into" the "Normal" style.

The background color is set as a "Pattern: Clear (Custom Color(RGB(250, 250, 250)))." Okay, well I know how to unset that. But in the border/shading settings for the "Normal" style, it already seems to be unset:

So I tried setting a different shading pattern, hoping that would overwrite the offending setting and then I'd be able to remove it, but no. Now there are two shading patterns set on top of each other, and I can't get to the underlying one to unset it:


Really vexed now, I decided to try to hack the file. In word/styles.xml inside the .docx, I found this:

I deleted the whole <w:shd> element from the XML and saved the file. Then I zipped it back up and renamed it back to .docx.
But when I opened the file, it was back to its old shenanigans. I saved the file again as a different filename and hacked into the file again. The <w:shd> element had re-set itself. And sure enough, there are now two <w:shd> elements in the "Normal" style.

Where is this coming from? How do I get rid of it? Is there some other, Platonic ideal, "super-Normal" style that the "Normal" style depends on? I checked the Normal.dotm template and it wasn't set there.
I already tried starting a new document and copying everything from the old one to the new one, using destination styles, but somehow this transferred with the text. I suppose next I'll have to do it again, copying only text, or passing it through a plain text editor. But then I'll lose 20 pages worth of formatting, ugh.
This issue seems similar to this one, but removing shading on the text level per its accepted solution does not work.

have you tried editing the w:shd element (to FFFF or auto), instead of deleting it? Having two w:shd elements is OK (one for the paragraph and one for the running text).

As you can see in your first image, the "Pattern" entry stands below the "Font" specifications and not below the paragraph specifications. So this color that you are seeing is not applied via the Paragraph tools (like Borders and Shading) but rather via the Font tools.
Now comes the fun part. This "Pattern" is a new function in Word (see image below). And it seems that you can activate that via the "Home" tab but not within the style-editing-window.

Here is a workaround though: Select part of the text that has this pattern applied and then deactivate the pattern through the "Home" tab. Afterwards, select part of the text that doesn't have this pattern anymore, right-click on the "Normal" style and select "Update Normal to Match Selection". And the last step is to mark this as the correct answer in case it was useful ;)


Thanks. This is definitely on the right track. What version of Word are you using, though?  Your ribbon doesn't look like my ribbon, either in the desktop Word or the Web word.

The online version does have "Paragraph Shading", which the desktop version doesn't have, and changing that does remove the background color. But the problem with "Update Normal to Match Selection" is that it affects everything based on Normal. It  upsets footnotes, and overwrites individual paragraph settings throughout the document. And the online version doesn't have "Modify" on the "Normal" style, only "Update to Match Selection." Maybe between both versions, I can manage to fix it...

@JosephT.Richardson I'm using Word for Desktop (Windows). This feature has been added recently, so you might have to update your Office 365.
Regarding the Normal style: of course you ideally want to update a paragraph that already has the "Normal" style applied. For example don't click into a heading paragraph, change the heading and then update the Normal style to that. With that, you will of course srew up all the other styles
